# Automation Execution

Tags: oracle, jenkins, automated-tests, jira, multi-user

We have a set of automation scripts shared among a group of testers. They all execute these scripts on a shared environment/database which is used by multiple groups. The problem is with the data preparation step of these scripts. one tester prepares his data and starts to run the script by when there are chances that his data gets modified by someone else's initiated process in the application. (both dev and testers use this box). How can we make sure to have each testers his own data which is not allowed to modify by others. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Look up flashback

Comment: why don't you use a separate schema for each tester/dev?

Comment: @ Ed Heal : Thanks for the reply. surely an option to look at which requires additional access which is not guaranteed from the client.

Comment: @ Cyrille Modiano : Thank you. not a feasible option for the application & db size. Client space.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the constraints you have? Are the changed data (when test runs) limited to small number of tables? Are you able to introduce more tables in the same schema?..

Answer (score 0):

Do not use shared environments for development or testing.

That's what 90% of Oracle shops do but it's a huge mistake.  In 2017 there is no reason each person cannot have an unlimited number of database instances.  There are many easy ways to do it, either on your PC or in the cloud.

This doesn't help you with your immediate problems but you need to create a long-term goal of "infinite instances".  Until you get there everyone will be stepping on each other's toes.

Comment: I would not generalize. There could be legitimate reasons behind the constraint!

Comment: @BA. I don't think I've ever heard a good reason to do it that way.  In my experience, people set it up that way because it's less work up front, and then rationalize it and accept it because "that's the way it's always been done".  It's my least favorite thing about the Oracle culture.

Comment: It is not always a contained dev/test sandbox.Think about security and access, integration to other systems/parties, data size, etc. And, if you find your self in a place like this, where it can be better, someone needs to manage until things are re-shapped..